# error in interact_plot() R - cannot be factor for variable that is not factor

Tags: r

I am trying to use interact_plot() in R to visualize my interaction.
I have three variables - a continuous outcome variable, a binary predictor, and a continuous moderator.

I used this code:
`interact_plot(fit2, pred=rise_indicator, modx=Years_Education_recode)`

I got the following error message:

```
  Focal predictor ("pred") cannot be a factor. Either use it as modx, convert it to a numeric dummy variable, or use the cat_plot function for factor by factor interaction plots.
```

I changed my variable to numeric using the following code:
`impact$rise_indicator<-as.numeric(as.character(impact$rise_indicator))`

`is.factor(impact$rise_indicator)`

`[1] FALSE`

When I re-run my model, I still get the same error message. I'm not sure why that is.

````
  Focal predictor ("pred") cannot be a factor. Either use it as modx, convert it to a numeric dummy variable, or use the cat_plot function for factor by factor interaction plots.```
````